# Collision detection in own game engine

Tags: c#, collision-detection, game-physics, aabb

I'm stuck on collision detection:

I've read about different ways of dealing with collisions, and choose to implement it with AABB. Problem appears right in the beginning: I have my test object - wood tower, and I'd like to enclose it with AABB object, I'm iterating through vertices to find min and max values for each axis, which works ok, but takes a lot time, even for single one object (It's quite big object I think ~8000 vertices).

What is proper way of doing it? Should data like this be in object files or I'm just doing it wrong way? Object may be big (I don't know if it is), but it's just one object, I'm afraid about what will happen when I set more of them

I'm writing with c# and OpenTK

Edit:

I know I should use the simplified collision model, I'm trying to find the boundaries over which I will build the AABB box (I had the screen hooked up, but it looks like mods didn't like it). Iterating over each vector seems somehow wrong (although it works, I have a nice box, fitted to the size of the model, but not in the effective processing time)

Comment: You shouldn't need to check them all every time; there are obvious ways to eliminate objects from detection. Say, the left side of object A is further to the right than the right side of object B; no reason to go any further. Same is true for their tops and bottoms. Not sure that helps.

Comment: I'm not dealing with checking it yet, I'm wondering which way of generating bounding value is the best

Comment: On a more general note, many games use simplified collision models or just primitives rather than high-poly visual models to check for collisions.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you should do that when creating the model resource file. I think your calculation method is fine as is.

And then if this model rotates or scales in your game, make a new AABB from the OBB(which was the AABB loaded from the file before transformation).